# Load subreport dynamically as main report in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, report, crystal-reports-2010

I have used this resource

http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_load_dynamically.htm

for adding reports dynamically from any database servers. However I am not able to load the sub reports after adding into the main report. It keeps on asking for server details.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Seems like it is asking for logon details. You need to write Backend code and specify database details, so that it can load data. Post code which you are using for report load, that will help. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/690337/How-can-I-remove-the-Database-Login-on-Crystal-Rep